# Go multiple response.WriteHeader calls for Fprint

Tags: http, go

I want to print out the text message first and below the text, diplay the image.
But I am getting `http: multiple response.WriteHeader calls` errors.

How do I serve iamges and text using one hadler in one single page?

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  fmt.Fprint(w, "Hello, world!")
  fp := path.Join("images", "gopher.png")
  http.ServeFile(w, r, fp)
}

func main() {
  http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
  http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't write text then call ServeFile to output a binary picture after the text.

If you want to serve text with the image then use html, setup a static file handler and use html:

```
var tmpl = `<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>%s</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>%s</h1>
    <div><img src="images/%s"></div>
    </body>
</html>
`

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, tmpl, "Hello, world!", "Hello, world!", "gopher.png")
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.Handle("/images/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("images/")))
    http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
}
```

Comment: Is there any other way to serve text with image?

Comment: @EPSILONsdfsdfdsf use html.

Comment: This works with static file but when I serve, the server cannot find the file

Comment: @EPSILONsdfsdfdsf are you sure you set the path right for the fileserver? http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileServer

Comment: You could also embed the image as a data URI in base64 encoding but I don't know how to do that exactly.